# Passing data to OPL model from Java

Tags: java, cplex, opl

I have OPL *.mod* model and I run it from Java code. The model needs some external data.
Currently model loads the data from *.dat* file with

```
IloOplFactory.createOplRunConfiguration(String modelName, String[] dataFiles)
```

method.

*I want to load the data directly from Java code.*

I found

```
IloOplFactory.createOplRunConfiguration(OplModelDefinition, OplDataElements)
```

but I can't understand how to use it (how to define elements for OplDataElements).

Could someone provide example of defining elements and usage of this method?
(Or better way to pass data from Java to OPL model)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this to pass in control and configuration data to a model, typically parameter values and flags. Once you create an instance of IloOplDataElements, you can just add it as a data source for your model, e.g.

```
IloOplDataElements configData = new IloOplDataElements(env);
configData.addElement(configData.makeElement("modelIteration", 1));
configData.addElement(configData.makeElement("debug", 2));
// etc
myModel.addDataSource(configData);
```

I haven't tried doing this with array data, but I guess it should be similar.